# Can I execute presto CLI without specifying --server or --catalog

Tags: presto

I would like to know where, if it is possible, I can configure default catalog and server values to use when executing the presto CLI.

Presto CLI info:

```
ls -lthr /opt/presto-server-0.169/presto

/opt/presto-server-0.169/presto -> presto-cli-0.169-executable.jar
```

And instead of executing:

```
/opt/presto-server-0.169/presto --server localhost:6666 --schema abc --catalog catalog-1
```

I would like to execute:

```
/opt/presto-server-0.169/presto
```

with it picking up `localhost:6666` as my server and `catalog-1` as my catalog. I would like to specify the schema once I make the connection.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: "if it is possible, I can configure default catalog and server values" -- would bash alias or a wrapper script do?

Comment: That wasn't something I thought of but is a good idea. Setting up an alias for each of the different catalogs I have configured would be very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option to set host in console lazily. The server needs to be defined upfront by default `localhost:8080` is used.

If you cannot pass proper arguments to the `presto-cli` and cannot use the default server host, you can change default values in `presto-cli` source code and compile your version.

- You need to checkout project at [github](https://github.com/prestodb/presto).
- Change default values in [ClientOptions](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/0.201/presto-cli/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/cli/ClientOptions.java#L51).
- Package jar for presto cli: `cd presto-cli && mvn package`
- You can find a jar in `target/presto-cli-0.201-SNAPSHOT.jar`

For schema/catalog, you can define it in the console itself with `USE` command. The syntax as follows: `USE [<catalog>.]<schema>`.

Please note that with each version of presto you need also compile and maintain your own version of `presto-cli`, which might become a burden quite soon.